# How to access child node in firebase with android studio

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an app that will be able to let you answer assessment questions. Now I have a problem on how to save the scores to the current user. I cannot access the child node. This is the real time database. How can I access the child node under Users

[image: Realtime Database]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use for loop to access the users just write this code under addOnEventListener:

```
DataSnapshot Users = datasnapshot.child("Users");
for(DataSnapshot userChild : Users.getChildren()){
    DataSnapshot email = userChild.child("email");
    String emailString = email.getValue(String.class);
}
```

Comment: what should i put inside the for loop?

Comment: how can i access the users?

Comment: You should get the values of you user i.e., email ,password and username. By accessing the children using userChild.child("username").getValue() to string

Comment: its still not working. pls help me

Comment: Can you update the code!!

Comment: I update the ans use this to get the email and other stuff